# PHP Unidentified Function script

Tags: mysql, cookies, php, minecraft

The code I am trying to use is below, Ive double checked it and everything and it keeps saying this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function Votifier() ,  I dont know what the problem is here. This is my last resort to ask here, Ive been googling for 2 hours.. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['votfed']) && $_COOKIE['vofted'] == 'true') {
    exit();
} else {
    mysql_connect("", "", "")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("")or die("cannot select DB");
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id = "' . $_GET["server"] . '"');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $public_key  = $row['votifier_key'];
        $server_ip   = $row['ip'];
        $server_port = $row['votifier_port'];
        $username    = 'USERNAME';
    }
    $username = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/", '', $username);
    if (Votifier($public_key, $server_ip, $server_port, $username)) {
        echo 'Success!';
    } else {
        echo 'Error!';
    }
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    function Votifier($public_key, $server_ip, $server_port, $username) {

        $public_key = wordwrap($public_key, 65, "\n", true);
        $public_key = <<<EOF
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
$public_key
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOF;
        $address    = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $timestamp  = time();
        $string     = "VOTE\MC-ServerLists.com\n$username\n$address\n$timeStamp\n";
        $leftover   = (256 - strlen($string)) / 2;
        while ($leftover > 0) {
            $string .= "\x0";
            $leftover--;
        }
        openssl_public_encrypt($string, $crypted, $public_key);
        $socket = fsockopen($server_ip, $server_port, $errno, $errstr, 3);
        if ($socket) {
            fwrite($socket, $crypted);

            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }

    mysql_connect("", "", "")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("")or die("cannot select DB");
    mysql_query('insert into voters (server_id, ipaddress) VALUES ("' . $_GET["server"] . '", "' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '")');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: This style of indentation is what's known as "wall of code". Please format your code so that it is readable, I don't imagine you have it looking like that in your editor. At least, I hope you don't.

Answer (score 5):

If you formatted your code correctly, you'd see that the function is conditionally defined, and because of this, its definition must occur before you call the function:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['votfed']) && $_COOKIE['vofted'] == 'true') {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
    $username = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/", '', $username);
    if (Votifier($public_key, $server_ip, $server_port, $username)) {
        echo 'Success!';
    } else {
        echo 'Error!';
    }
    function Votifier($public_key, $server_ip, $server_port, $username)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
?>
```

Essentially, you are executing this code:

```
<?php
if( false) {
} else {
    if( foo()) { 
        echo 'Foo!'; 
    }
    function foo() { 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Which should show you that `foo()` is not defined until after the `else` executes, but you call `foo()` at the beginning of the `else` block (before it's defined).

Your function should be outside of the `if` statement, like this:

```
<?php
function Votifier($public_key, $server_ip, $server_port, $username)
{
    // ...
}
if (isset($_COOKIE['votfed']) && $_COOKIE['vofted'] == 'true') {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
    $username = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/", '', $username);
    if (Votifier($public_key, $server_ip, $server_port, $username)) {
        echo 'Success!';
    } else {
        echo 'Error!';
    }
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can place it at the beginning of the `else` block, but I wouldn't recommend it from a readability standpoint.

Comment: +1 but minor (pedantic) correction - the function is defined in the correct "scope", but because it is defined conditionally it must be defined before it can be used. If functions are defined in the global "scope" (i.e. not conditionally or otherwise at call time) then their position in the file relative to the calling code does not matter.

Comment: @Dave - I thought I was doing a bad job of explaining that. Thanks, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Also you didn't point out the undefined variable warning about `$timeStamp`... ;)